# If else statement in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

i want to create `if-else` statement in codeigniter with my logic

```
If $language === "english"
```

it will no change

```
$q["question_title"] = $q["question_title"]
```

else

it will change

```
$q["question_title"] = $q["question_title_**id**"]
```

the point is, i want to add `"_id"` in every php if `$languege = no "english"`

how to do that if php code inside of `"[]"` like `$q["question_title"]`

**OR**
from query.php

```
    // translation language
    $site_lang = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');
    if ( $site_lang === 'english') {
    $question['questions'][$i]['question_title'] = $q->quiz_text;
    } else {
    $question['questions'][$i]['question_title'] = $q->quiz_text_id;
    }
```

so if i use code in /views  and it read cookies in "english" it will get database "quiz_text" but if else it will get "quiz_text_id" from database
but it not work in my query code.

Comment: `echo $site_lang;` what you getting?

Comment: it should be only this ::  if ( $site_lang == 'english') { // remove === to by ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `echo $site_lang` what you getting then keep condition simple if title has already you don't need to set same value again so do a check like

```
$site_lang = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');
if ( $site_lang != 'english') {
  $question['questions'][$i]['question_title'] = $q->quiz_text_id;
}
```

Comment: i use it in query.php but not change anythings

Comment: have you cheked by echoing values